# Как запустить бат файл через servlet

Tags: java, servlet

Пытаюсь запустить бат файл через servlet, файл видит, но запускать не хочет.
Если запускать не через servlet, то все запускается...

```
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
    resp.getWriter().write("Hello");
    start();
}

private void start(){
    try {
        ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "111.bat");
        Process process = builder.start();
    }catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
  }
}
```

Comment: Есть подозрение, что на сервере, где выполняется ваше веб приложение, нет файла 111.бат. Или cmd.exe не находит. Читайте стектрейс

Comment: Действительно, не мог найти батник, тк как директория по умолчанию другая была